# I am moving to another country and not sure how my current job translates to the job roles in the other country

Tags: software-industry, new-job, job-change, india, different-countries

Currently in the Us, I am a Team Manager and the job requires me to do technical project management as well as people management.
I am in charge of deliveries, strategic planning around initiatives as well as people management for my teams. I do not code or do any architectural reviews. I lean on my tech leads to do that with group architects. So in a way I am an Engineering Manager.
But I am moving to another country now, where Engineering manager roles mean one who does and can get his hands dirty in code, architecture etc. Not sure if in India, the role that I am currently doing is a Delivery Manager role?
Please advise whether Delivery Manager role is actually what I think it is - Tech Project Management plus People management? And should I stick with Engineering manager role instead?

Answer (score 1):

Job titles can be anything.

You need to read and understand the job descriptions before applying.

Comment: It is an internal transfer. I get to ask them to transfer to either.

Comment: should still have a job description.

Comment: What I do is a mix of both. So I can fit into either.

Comment: then why not just pick the higher paying one?